# Could someone please someone translate 舒心顺气茶

Tags: translation

Could someone please someone translate 舒心顺气茶

Thank you

Comment: look up 舒心,顺气,茶 if necessary, bkrs:舒心:comfortable happy topo.1) pleasant and agreeable 2) comfortable; happy   also note http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A1%BA%E6%B0%94  **顺气食物**   (regulating qi)
 七种顺气食物应常吃  esp. 玫瑰花：沏  **茶**  时放几瓣玫瑰花可顺气，没有喝 **茶**  习惯者可以单独泡玫瑰花喝。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**舒** + ***心***: **comfort** (verb) + ***heart*** (noun)
be comfortable
**顺** + ***气***: **smooth** (verb) + ***breath*** (noun)
breath smoothly
***茶***: tea

舒心顺气茶: 
The tea that comfort your heart and smooth your breath (after drinking)
This is exaggerative practically, it is a beautiful name only.

There some more similar medicine name prefix like 活血化瘀, 补气养血, 健胃消食, 舒筋活络, etc.
Generally they are all four characters with two words, the first word made up with former two characters, and the second one with later two characters.
The 1st and 3rd ones are verbs, they have similar meanings, or they are two different words in same scopes, or they are separated from one two-character-word, the 2nd and 4th ones are nouns, the same structure as above.

For example, some Chinese 成语 (chengyu), or 四字成语 (Chinese 4-word idioms):
**身**强**体**壮 means strong body, strong physique
**身体**: body, corporeity, 强壮: muscular.
**筋**疲**力**尽 means exhaust you physically and mentally
**筋**: tendon, bone, 疲: tired, **力**: force, strength, 尽: spent, used up

Answer (score 0):

It is a name of a product. And it is difficult to translate it directictly from Chinese to English. It is better to use the meaning of it to translate it.
"舒心顺气" is to make people feel comfortable and relax. Do not pay attention on 心 or 气. 舒心顺气 is not a 4-word idiom, it can be explain as an adj. It does not mean it will really help with people's heart or breath. It just discribe a kind of feeling that can make people feel relax.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a name of a kind of tea. Same as "red smooth ball". "舒心顺气" are
some words to describe the functions of the tea.It means that if you drink this kind of tea, you will be "舒心 & 顺气"